# Can I extract strings that contain any of a vector of strings in R

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors of strings and I want to create a subset of strings if any of the strings from the first vector appear in the 2nd. The subset should include the 2nd vector of strings (y) not the first (x).

I've tried grepl and str_extract but neither really work. I get a warning that the pattern has a length > 1 with grepl. str_extract will only work on the words if the order matches. It doesn't consider every occurence. Here's an example:

```
x<-c("pop", "bub", "gre", "cab", 'xyz')
y<-c("bubble bath", "babbling brook", "green frogs", "abc 123", "pop goes the weasel")
str_extract(y,x)
```

In the example above, only "gre" will be returned, but "pop" and "bub" should also come back since they match with "bubble bath" and "pop goes the weasel". Also, I would like to create a subset of y that has matched, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the outer of x and y with a vectorized grepl, then use which to give you the matching indices for x and y.

```
ind <- which(outer(x, y, Vectorize(grepl)), arr.ind = T)
x[ind[,1]]
# [1] "bub" "gre" "pop"
y[ind[,2]]
# [1] "bubble bath"         "green frogs"         "pop goes the weasel"
```

as a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(Map('[', data.frame(x, y), as.data.frame(ind)))
#     x                   y
# 1 bub         bubble bath
# 2 gre         green frogs
# 3 pop pop goes the weasel
```

Comment: Very creative solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
str_extract(y, paste(x, collapse="|"))
# [1] "bub" NA    "gre" NA    "pop"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
x[sapply(x, function(xi) any(grepl(xi, x=y, fixed=TRUE)))]
# > x[sapply(x, function(xi) any(grepl(xi, x=y, fixed=TRUE)))]
# [1] "pop" "bub" "gre"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-c("pop", "bub", "gre", "cab", 'xyz')
y<-c("bubble bath", "babbling brook", "green frogs", "abc 123", "pop goes the weasel")

get_ind <- function(w, x){
  any(grepl(w,x))
}

x[sapply(x, get_ind, x = y)]
```